# Binning two columns of data simultaneously

Tags: r, binning

I have two columns of data, one that contains a set of values and the other their corresponding pearson coefficient values (both are 41306329 long). I want to bin my data to the first column, so that any values that fall within a set bin range also have their corresponding pearson coefficient values contained within those bins. However, once that is done, I then want to bin those pearson coefficient values. So for example, with:-

```
column1 <- as.numeric(c("100.01", "100.015", "100.017", "100.071", "100.099", "100.111", "100.153", "100.167"))
column2 <- as.numeric(c("0.89", "0.64", "-0.14", "-0.79", "1", "0.31", "-0.27", "0.45"))
test <- cbind(column1, column2)
bin1 <- seq(100, 100.2, by = 0.05)
bin2 <- seq(-1, 1, by = 0.5)
```

I need a way to bin the values so that I get the bin range of (100,100.05] (100.05,100.1] (100.1,100.15] (100.15,100.2] with the values falling within their respective bins, before binning their corresponding pearson coefficient values from -1 to +1 and from that, produce a 3D scatter plot which describes the distribution of the values from the first column using the pearson coefficient values. In effect, it would produce a graph of values (column1) vs pearson coefficient (column2) vs frequency.

The graph would look something like this:- 
[image]

I hope this makes sense! Thanks!

Comment: Why you are creating character columns ?

Comment: Ah forgot to include my conversion into numeric vectors, shall edit it now

Comment: No problem.  Do you need to cbind the new bin columns to `test` or create that as a new dataset?

Comment: Preferably cbind it to test!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
 res <- data.frame(Map(function(x,y) cut(x, breaks=y),
                    as.data.frame(test), list(bin1, bin2)))

 res1 <- cbind(test, res)
```